# Oracle SQL issue while inserting multiple rows into a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the following query to insert multiple rows into a table `my_employee` :

```
insert all into 
  my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary) values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
  my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary) values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
  my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary) values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
select * from DUAL;
```

yet I followed similar questions step by stet ,but I don't know why I'm getting this error :

```
Erreur SQL : ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `into` for each insert. This should work:

```
insert all 
  into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary) values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
  into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary) values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
  into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary) values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
select * from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with three insert statements:

```
insert into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
    values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary);

insert into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
    values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary);

insert into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
    values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary);
```

Or with one statement using `union all`:

```
insert into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
    select &id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary
    from dual union all
    select &id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary
    from dual union all
    select &id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary;
```

I don't see an application for `insert all` because you want to insert into a single table.

Answer (score 1):

IN MSSQL

```
insert into my_employee (id, last_name, first_name, userid, salary)
    values (&id, '&last_name', '&firstname', '&userid', &salary)
go 100;
```

it will inserts 100 rows with same value